# can not install waterlock local auth

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterlock

I am trying to use waterlock for authentication. i have installed waterlock but failing to install waterkick-local-auth.  the error message is shown bellow:

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-34-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/developer/Desktop/Sails/AuthTest/node_modules/waterlock-local-auth/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "waterlock-local-auth"
npm ERR! node v0.12.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.7.8 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.7.8 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/developer/Desktop/Sails/AuthTest/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By studying the documentation of the waterlock local auth i have come to an solution is that the problem is caused for the dependencies of waterlock local auth.

```
I am using the latest node version.
```

And to make this work i need to downgrade the node version. And then all the dependencies will work.